# mysql_result is defined but mysql_free_result warns it expected a resource

Tags: php, mysql

This code tests to see if there was a result before freeing it up:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("$query\n\n" . mysql_error());
$id = mysql_insert_id();
if ($result) { mysql_free_result($result); }
```

But it gives this warning:

```
mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /foo/bar/etc.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have called `mysql_insert_id()`, I assume you performed an `INSERT` query rather than a `SELECT`. In that case (as with others where no rowset is returned), `$result` is merely a boolean TRUE on success, not a result resource.  There's no need to free it, and indeed trying to free it results in a warning.

[From the documentation on `mysql_query()`:](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

However, that doesn't mean you shouldn't error-check it.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
  $id = mysql_insert_id();
}
else echo mysql_error();
```